# Burninate the [Future] tag on meta

Tags: discussion, meta, burninate-request

It's kinda dopey, and it's only been used once this year.  I think it's time to dump the [future](/questions/tagged/future) tag.  The questions asked don't really need it.

Comment: I don't want to live in the past though!

Comment: And there's no [Past] tag.

Comment: Tags?  Where we're going, we don't need tags.

Comment: Wait, do we really have a [meta-tag:future] tag on Meta, too? o.o Can we turn this into a double-burninate request?

Comment: *tries to resist making another BttF joke*

Comment: No.  There's no Double-Burninate tag.

Comment: Uhhh. [future] has been used on SO many times and is a legitimate programming concept which certainly does not need burninating (might be worth pluralizing though? Not sure). I'm pretty sure you mean the one on meta. Let me fix that tag link for you.

Comment: Wait, you tagged a burninate request with the tag you want removed? Isn't that a bit self-defeating?

Comment: @Generic Holiday Name: He's envisioning a future in which the [future] tag no longer exists.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: Personally, I'd like to see the tag magically disappear with a refresh of my browser. :-)

Comment: Like Calvin from Calvin and Hobbes said, "Our problem is that the future keeps becoming the present"

Comment: I'm sad to see this go, personally, I would have preferred a [Past] and [Present] tag to go alongside this, all of them are obviously going to be incredibly useful. :(


(Why was this even...)

Answer (score 1):

I removed [future](/questions/tagged/future) from all the questions. ( Including this question ;) )